# lookup within date range excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, row, lookup

[image]

[image]

table 1.
date and time the booking was made

table 2.
The values remain in place until the next date/time its modified.

What I want to know: what was the value from table 2 at the time the booking was made.

Result: I want value '1' from the table 2 because the booking was made on the 22/06/21 11:00, and at that time, the value '1' from Table 2 was in place until the 23/06.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(Table2[value],MATCH(LARGE(IF(Table2[date modified]<[@[Date Time]],Table2[date modified]),1),Table2[date modified],0))`
[image]

Comment: thank you, how does it work when there is multiple keys.  i.e. abc111, abc222.  still in both tables.  how do i match to the keys as well?  i want abc111 to get abc111 value.... abc222 to get abc222 value.

Comment: `=INDEX(Table2[value],MATCH(LARGE(IF(Table2[date modified]<[@[Date Time]],Table2[date modified])*(Table2[key]=[@key]),1),Table2[date modified],0))`